# Task Scheduler Batch File with Configuration

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I'm currently using APEX Data loader to download Raw files from Salesforce.

Using the command line I can download the data that I need by simply typing the command.

Now I need to schedule the task so I don't need to do it everyday.

I run the dataloader by typing in the following

C:/Program Files (x86)/salesforce.com/data loader/bin/process.bat C:/datadownload/

C:/datadownload contains the configuration file I need to connect to Salesforce.

How can I set this thing up with Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved By creating another batch file... CALLing the Process.bat and adding the location of the file

Answer (score 0):

Create another batch file with the same command - note the double quotes - and schedule that batch file in task scheduler.  When you've done that then launch the scheduled task manually (right click on the task) to test that it works.  Provide credentials and an account if it is to run when you aren't logged in.

I added the call command in case you want to add any post-processing tasks to the batch file later.

```
@echo off
call "C:/Program Files (x86)/salesforce.com/data loader/bin/process.bat" C:/datadownload/
```